# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04LTS, Dell XPS 15

Tags: sound, dell, alsa

I had some trouble with my Dell XPS15 9560. 
I have no sound at all. Tried to solve this with alsamixer, it doesn't work. 
Sometimes my alsamixer won't launch as well. 
My sound settings do look like this

[image]

And I know for sure that it is not hardware problem as well, in Windows it works just fine.

Comment: XPS 15 ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, neither gives me any sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostly the problem like your's is dew to missing adherance to the right audio group for your user account with which you are trying using audio.

So if you open the gnome-terminal or xterm, and type this command like the user "lenny" bellow and you would get similar output, with the group audio in place.

```
lenny@lennyPC~  id | grep audio
uid=2146(lenny) gid=2146(lenny) groups=2146(lenny),24(cdrom),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),110(lxd),129(pulse-access),137(wireshark) ...and perhaps more other group names with group numbers...
```

.... - then my guess is wrong and you can skip the rest of this answer,

but if you get nothing as the result, -then you should add yourself

or all your users that should be able to access sound resources to

the groups audio and pulse-access.

This can be done in the terminal window, - like so:

```
<17:07:12>lenny@lennyPC:~$ sudo adduser lenny pulse-access
Adding user `lenny' to group `pulse-access' ...
Adding user lenny to group pulse-access
Done.

<17:07:27>lenny@lennyPC:~$ sudo adduser lenny audio
Adding user `lenny' to group `audio' ...
Adding user lenny to group audio
Done.
```

After you would do this, you can check that your account now has the needed audio groups with the same command:

id | grep audio

and now you should get the output as by me in the case of lenny.

But you need to log  out from your grafical screen and then login again before your sound should begin to work. It is because your grafic environment will only then get to know about your new access groups and let you use your sound card.

Comment: Does not work for me either, XPS 15, now Ubuntu 18.04, still no joy.